# How to add a shortcut to the list of installed apps (or to a widget)?

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean, lock-screens, home-screen-shortcuts

I have an app ([Pleco](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.pleco.chinesesystem)) which has created a shortcut (study flashcards). I want to execute that shortcut from the screenlocker ([Go Locker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jiubang.goscreenlock)), but it only allows to add either installed apps or widgets.

My idea to solve this issue was to create an app from the shortcut. I tried with Tasker and its AutoShortcut plugin as it is suggested [here](http://hackerspace.lifehacker.com/you-can-add-shortcuts-to-basically-anywhere-1066122635), but the built app simply does not work.

Is it a correct procedure to solve this issue? Another possibily would be to add the shortcut to a widget, but how?

Comment: From the page you linked: _It seems you can use Tasker to launch activities too as long as you have the Tasker Plugin AutoShortcut installed and you are using a launcher that allows you to access the "Activities" list from it's shortcut screen (like Nova or Apex)._ Which launcher are you using?

Comment: @FranciscoAlvarado, Tasker launches the app correctly from inside, but if I export it as app (to add it to the list of installed apps), the exported app doesn't work. If I install Nova or Apex, it should be executable from Nova or Apex, but not from the screenlocker (Go Locker)